# Why does Google's AMP Project (Accelerated Mobile Pages) ban form and input tags?

Tags: amp-html

According to the
[specs](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-html-format.md)
the AMP project bans HTML tags like form, input, textarea, select and option.

However, [Google's AMP Search Page](https://www.google.de/webhp?esrch=AcceleratedMobilePages::Preview,AcceleratedMobilePagesDesktop::Promo&gws_rd=cr&ei=1HwXVq2YHcWdsgGvkbY4) uses a form and input tag.

What's the reason for banning input elements?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: That page isnt actully an 'AMP' page (it doesnt contain <html ⚡>). Its just a 'loader', it can search for and load AMP pages. I imagine the banning is for security reasons, eg preventing insecure submissions. But also as the content can be loaded from a Google domain,  need to avoid XSS issues.

Answer (score 9):

Per Malte Ubl's comment on 1/11/2017, form support has been launched. See http://ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-form.

Previous answers that I provided are now outdated, but preserved below.  Thanks.

========================================

See the answer provided by @nickh for more recent developments with AMP.  Google's "Intent to Implement: AMP Forms Support" will supersede my old answer.  My answer below was provided in October 2015, and is now outdated. Thanks!

========================================

Since the focus of AMP is static web pages, form elements would seem to be out of scope.

Per the GitHub proof of concept: "AMP HTML is a way to build web pages for **static content** that render with reliable, fast performance."
https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml

And the October 7, 2015 announcement states, "We decided to focus entirely on **static content** as it lends itself to more radical optimization approaches that are easier to apply across the board."
https://www.ampproject.org/how-it-works/

Essentially Google is addressing low hanging fruit in web technology.

Comment: Form support is now launched https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-form

Answer (score 5):

A first version of the [amp-form](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/extended/amp-form.html) component has been implemented and can now be enabled as an experimental feature. `amp-form` allows HTTP and XHR (XMLHttpRequest) form submissions. You can find some samples [here](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-form/).

Answer (score 3):

amp-form is now a supported feature of AMP: https://amphtml.wordpress.com/2016/10/31/forms-now-supported-in-amp/

Answer (score 2):

In May 2016, an [Intent to Implement](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/3343) was created for AMP to support forms.

The implementation is partially complete, and AMP supports forms and inputs with certain attributes. See [the documentation for `amp-form`](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/extensions/amp-form/amp-form.md).